# Code signing in project settings, target settings and re-signing after creating the archive

Tags: iphone, ipad, provisioning, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I have seen a few questions similar to this. So the target settings override the project settings. I got that, but if I don't want to override the project settings, is that what the "Don't Sign" option is for?

What am I supposed to do after archiving my app, when it asks if I want to re-sign it? If I have set the signing at the project or target level, should this be set to "Don't Sign"? What happens if I elect to re-sign it? Does the signing done during the previous archiving step get overridden and replaced with the new choice?

Can I look into an archive (.ipa) file and see what provisioning profile was used? I don't see the option in Finder to open it like I can open other bundles. How can I do this?

Comment: To mooch around inside an IPA:  rename IPA to ZIP -> go inside and then open Payload folder -> rename APP to ZIP -> open it and find the mobileprovision file -> the name of the provisioning profile that was used should be in there.

Answer (score 1):

Just unzip the ipa (unzip appname.ipa) and do the following on the results:

codesign -dvv Payload/appname.app

It should show you the cert used.

Comment: I went to my .app file in the terminal can was able to cd into myapp.app. I didn't unzip it, as it looked like it was being treated as an accessible folder already. There is no folder there called Payload. So the command failed.

Comment: Jim you should have unzipped it as he said: unzip appname.ipa, which will create the Payload dir